# Finding MAC key, encryption key and initialization vector of the master secret in OpenSSL API codes

Tags: ssl, openssl

I have been wandering in OpenSSL API C files for quite some time to find where, in c files of OpenSSL, master secret is actually generated and is divided in three parts like MAC key, encryption key and initialization vector?

If you know it, please help me to spot it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ... master secret is actually generated and is divided in three parts like MAC key, encryption key and initialization vector ... If you know it, please help me to spot it.

Since you are talking about 6 keys rather than 4 keys (the client and server gets its own set), you are asking for SSLv3 and above (and not SSLv2).

You can find the code in `<openssl src>/ssl/s3_lib.c` and `<openssl src>/ssl/t1_lib.c`.

You can download the sources from [OpenSSL: Source, Tarballs](https://www.openssl.org/source/).